# What's the best way of asking the user to enter 2 integers in class a and add them in class b and have a display function in class C?

Tags: c#

I wanted to know how best to go about this. I have skeleton code to explain my question below I understand it's not complete and will contain errors.

But I want to take input in class `a`, add input in class `b`. Display result in class `c` and call the functions from `main()`. I do know couple ways but want to know the best way to do this.

```
class a
{
    public void input()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number");
        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number");
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

class b : a
{
    public void sum()
    {
        int result = num1 + num2;
    }

    class c : b
    {
        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you entered {0} and {1} the sum is {2}", num1, num2, result);
        }
    }
}

public void main()
{
    A acall = new A();
    B bcall = new B()
    c call = new c();
    a.input();
    b.sum();
    c.display();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'best way of asking the user to enter 2 integers'? Are you asking about refactoring?

Comment: well i mean just a way an expert would do it :)

Comment: Then I think you should take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com. It is a special place where user can post his **working** but ugly code and get some advice.
Currently your question is an off-topic for SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user experience. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code made me have a heart attack! Have a look at what I've provided to you below...

```
void Main()
{
    var fooBar = new FooBar();

    fooBar.GetInput();
    fooBar.Calculate();
    fooBar.Display();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public int SecondNumber { get; set; }

    public void GetInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number");
        this.FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number");
        this.SecondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public void Calculate()
    {   
        this.Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }

}

public class FooBar : Bar 
{

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", this.FirstNumber, this.SecondNumber, this.Result);
    }
}
```